# mariadb-mysql permissions issue

Tags: mysql, permissions, mariadb

I have an issues in that when i try to execute a stored procedure through my web application, i am shown the following error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 INSERT command denied to user 'elitecareers_admin'@'%' for table 'user'
```

Here is my stored procedure just for clarity

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_create_account`( username_param VARCHAR(40), email_param VARCHAR(60), pass_w VARCHAR(30), category_id TINYINT )
BEGIN 
    DECLARE salt VARCHAR(60);
    DECLARE password_var VARCHAR(128);

    SET salt = 'ELiCrs@4$^7EC%?';
    SET salt = CONCAT( username_param, salt );
    SET password_var = SHA2( CONCAT( pass_w, salt ), 0 );

    INSERT INTO elite.user
    ( user_id, username, email, pass, active, date_joined, user_category_id )
    VALUES
    ( DEFAULT, username_param, email_param, password_var, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, category_id );
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

and here is how the stored procedure looks when i run the show command
[image]

Here is my server information too
[image]

Here are the privileges for the user 'elitecareers_admin'@'%' under which the web application is executing
[image]

What i don't understand if the user has all privileges on the database, then why does mysql/maria server keeping those errors?

Comment: Maybe you just need `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: @Hackerman do not mix up mysql's user table with an ordinary table called user!

Comment: @Shadow I don't understand...can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: In the stored proc you insert into elite.user, while the grants apply to `elitecareers\_elite` database. The 2 database names do not match.

Comment: Do `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE sp_create_account \G` to find who created the proc and whether the 'security' is 'invoker' or 'owner'.

Comment: @Rick James    I have just added the show command for the stored procedure, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

"The SQL SECURITY characteristic can be DEFINER or INVOKER to specify the security context; that is, whether the routine executes using the privileges of the account named in the routine DEFINER clause or the user who invokes it. This account must have permission to access the database with which the routine is associated. **The default value is DEFINER.** The user who invokes the routine must have the EXECUTE privilege for it, as must the DEFINER account if the routine executes in definer security context. " -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

So, regardless of who runs the proc, the permissions for `'elitecareers_admin'@'%'` will be used for things such as accessing the table `elite`.`user`.  But that user seems to have privileges only to the database `elitecareers\_elite`.

Plan A: Recreate the proc with `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` *if* that is appropriate.

Plan B: Figure out the difference between databases `elite` and `elitecareers\_elite`.

Plan C: Add another `GRANT` to let that admin get to `elite`.

Plan D: (There are probably other solutions.)